How can I integrate my POST route in API gateway REST with my event bridge
I created a rest API with API GATEWAY, and I cannot integate my POST route 'sendMessage' with a amazon event bus(that have 2 rules). I need do a directly integration with my REST API  and event bridge
aws console api blank fields image
What i need to put in this fields?
I try put a execution role from my event buses, but when I tested my route I got a error message.
I just wanna do a directly integration with eventBridge

Just to clarify: you want to use EventBridge as a target in API GW or API GW as a target in an EventBridge rule?

I want to use the EventBridge as a target

Here's a SAM example which you can use as reference: https://serverlessland.com/patterns/apigateway-http-eventbridge
And here's a blog with some additional detail: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/capturing-client-events-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-eventbridge/
Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-console.html#how-to-method-settings-console-aws
